# Regex "allergic" to * and () and umlaute?

Tags: php, regex

I have the two following regular expressions and I am wondering what reason there is why they do not work:

```
$regex='#<br><h1 class="band name">(.+?)</h1><span class="bandinfotop">#';
preg_match($regex,$content,$match);
$name=$match[1];
```

In the cases where it does work, the selected string is something like for example **Häuptling and "(R) Brechende Zäune". An example where it does work is "!n:fact".

Now I am wondering whether it might be because of any specific signs in the string that mess up my regular expression? Like umlauts?

Later in the code I am doing this:

```
$name=strip_tags($name);
$name=htmlentities($name,null,"UTF-8");
if($name=="") $name="NULL";
```

For the ones that it didn't find a match for it echoes out "NULL".

Thankful for any help!
Charles

EDIT 1
It seems to be the last three lines - when the two before the last one are commented out, it works fine.

SOLUTION
When I removed the parameters null and "UTF-8" in htmlentities() then it worked somehow. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Just a quick shot, but what about using the `u` modifier for UTF-8?

Comment: @hakre what is the u modifier? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if the site your scrapping from has a spruce up and removes the `<br>` or adds a space between `</h1>` and `<span` your regex will break. Dont use regex for html parsing!

Instead use a dom parser like [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), or simply phps native [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
<?php 
$source = '<br><h1 class="band name">Häuptling and "(R) Brechende Zäune</h1><span class="bandinfotop">';


header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$return = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
@$dom->loadHTML($source);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('h1') as $headings) {
    if($headings->getAttribute('class') == "band name"){
        $title = $headings->nodeValue;
    }
}

echo $title; //Häuptling and "(R) Brechende Zäune
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing is more reliable then regex:

```
   $yourhtml = '<br><h1 class="band name">argh!</h1><span class="bandinfotop">';
   $dom = new DOMDocument();
   $dom->recover = true;
   $dom->loadHTML($yourhtml);
   $x = new DOMXPath($dom);
   foreach($x->query('//h1[@class="band name"]') as $node) var_dump($node->nodeValue);
```

But you regex works too:

```
   $content = '<br><h1 class="band name">**Häuptling and "(R) Brechende Zäune"</h1><span class="bandinfotop">';
   $regex='#<br><h1 class="band name">(.+?)</h1><span class="bandinfotop">#';
   preg_match($regex,$content,$match);
   var_dump(htmlentities(strip_tags($match[1]),null,'utf-8'));
   $content = '<br><h1 class="band name">!n:fact"</h1><span class="bandinfotop">';
   preg_match($regex,$content,$match);
   var_dump(htmlentities(strip_tags($match[1]),null,'utf-8'));

   //string(47) "**H&auml;uptling and "(R) Brechende Z&auml;une""
   //string(8) "!n:fact""
```

... so your particular problem is Somewhere Else.

Comment: thank you very much! I found the solution, see question edit, but do not yet know why it works - do you know why?

Comment: logic dictates your input is not utf-8, but something else.... You could set the second argument to `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE`, but it's more advisable to give the actual character set of the input string.